# How to implement Popup on .NET MAUI application

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui

Is there any way to implement Popups in .NET MAUI applications using the plugin Rg.Plugins.Popup or
other way to achive this?

Comment: Hi! Which kind of Pop-ups do you need? Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups)

Comment: Open pages as popup like Rg.Plugins.Popup [link](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Pop)

Comment: The only component of Xamarin Forms that ever worked ... was Rg.Plugins.Popup (!)

Comment: @sina there's port for MAUI: https://github.com/LuckyDucko/Mopups

Answer (score 4):

As long as Rg.Plugins.Popup (or any other third-party library) does not update to be compatible with .NET MAUI, you can't use them.

A popup mechanism is available in the [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/), which has a version that is [compatible with .NET MAUI in preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat/). Or use the popups that are [available in .NET MAUI directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups). The docs will mention Xamarin.Forms, but this should also be available in .NET MAUI.

Specific to Rg.Plugins.Popup, at the time of writing, not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i always get errors when using the Xamarin Community Toolkit : I installed the package Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat, then I added  xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit" in my xaml page but I get the error "type xct:Popup not found"

Comment: You should be able to ignore that error and still use it. It's a false tooling error unfortunately. You should be able to get around it by not using that URL namespace but the full namespace instead

Answer (score 3):

Hi to everyone searching now:

Rg.Plugins.Popup has been ported to .net maui under the new name Mopups. You can find it as NuGet and on https://github.com/LuckyDucko/Mopups Documentation seems to be limited as apparently it is nearly identical to the way you used Rg.Plugins.Popups for Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Gerald actually made a useful video about it: https://youtu.be/OGWhgASmSto

Answer (score 1):

If that is still valid, here is a quick hint for you how to achieve that with the CommunityToolkit functionality without using any third-party packages, which are not supported by Microsoft team, just for showing popup:

```
await Shell.Current.CurrentPage.ShowPopupAsync(customPopup);
```

Just put that code whenever you think it should be, whether it is your viewmodel (which I don't recommend it), or right into your Navigation service implementation.

Comment: This is not a builtin functionality of MAUI. You need a dependency on CommunityToolkit.Maui. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup).

Comment: My mistake, thanks @kegesch) 
Just like Essentials, the CommunityToolkit is kind of the package that is almost always included, I'd even say that it should be included due to its useful functionality. Updated my answer)

Comment: In my case this worked,  Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopup(new ListPopup());